# How do I invert the results of my RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation

I have the following RegEx

`.*\.(test|spec|es5|es6)\.(js|bundle\.js)`

With the following test inputs

```
bunle.spec.js
my.main.js
test.es6.js
te.es5.js
file.test.js
abc.js
ee.ff.abc.js
eeee.ffff.abc.js
```

https://regex101.com/r/8BZyA0/2

How do I flip my RegEx condition, so it picks `my.main.js`, `abc.js`,  `ee.ff.abc.js` and `eeee.ffff.abc.js`
instead?

Thanks

Comment: It's easy to say what you don't want using a negative assertion, but you have to combine it with a form you do want. If you don't combine with the valid form, you will just get anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the first part of the pattern you have into a negative lookahead and anchor it at the start of the string, and - as per the feedback in the comments - you need the string to end with `.js` or `.bundle.js` - add the `$` anchor at the end:

```
 ^(?!.*\.(?:test|spec|es[56])\.(?:(?:bundle\.)?js$)).*\.(?:bu‌​ndle\.)?js$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ouEFwj/1).

**Details**:

- `^` - start of the string
- `(?!.*\.(?:test|spec|es[56])\.(?:(?:bundle\.)?js$))` - a negative lookahead that will fail a match if *after 0+ chars other than line break chars* (due to `.*`) a string contains `.` followed with `test`, `spec`, `es5` or  `es6` followed with `.` and then `js` or `bundle.js` at the end of the string (`$`)
- `.*` - 0+ chars other than line break chars
- `\.` - a dot
- `(?:bu‌​ndle\.)?` - an optional non-capturing group matching 1 or 0 occurrences of `bundle.` substring
- `js` - a literal substring `js`
- `$` - at the end of the string.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was trying `.*\.(?!test|spec|es5|es6)\.(js|bundle\.js)` and `.*\.(?!(?:test|spec|es5|es6))\.(js|bundle\.js)` but didn't make it. I don't know why.

Comment: They did not work because you used negative lookaheads before `\.(js|bundle\.js)` patterns, thus restricting them. However, those lookaheads returned true all the time, as the first consuming pattern is a `\.` (literal dot) and it is not equal to either `t`, `s` or `e`.

Comment: Oh, so to stop the negative lookaheads from looking into the following pattern, we need to use the capturing Group there, right?

Comment: No, the lookahead should be *anchored* and its pattern must be able to get to the forbidden pattern. In my solution, `^` makes the lookahead anchored at the start of the string (=it will be executed once at the start of the string) and then `.*` will match all the line up to its end, then backtracking will occur, and whenever the engine finds a `\.(?:test|spec|es[56])\.(?:(?:bundle\.)?js` match *anywhere on its way to the start of the line*, the lookahead will fail the match.

Comment: Perhaps, you want to match strings having `.js` or `.bundle.js` at the end of the string, not preceded with `.test`, `.spec`, `.es5`, `es6`? Then use [`^(?!.*\.(?:test|spec|es[56])\.(?:(?:bundle\.)?js$)).*\.(?:bundle\.)?js$`](https://regex101.com/r/ouEFwj/1).